# Centralized Logs Storage for Load Balanced Managed Instance Group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have setup a Managed Instance Group with initial 3 instances (I installed Lumen inside, and the web server is auto started) to be used with the GCP load balancer. The LB works great.

However, whenever I need to trace lumen logs, I need to SSH every single instance to view the logs. Is there any best practices of one centralized storage I can refer to for the logs?

Can I mount the lumen logs into a centralized disk e.g. GCP filestore volume, or Google storage bucket or using FluendD to dump my logs into GCP Logging?

Please, I need to know the best industrial practice. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STACK DRIVER is the right option for your case

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#joint-install

Install the stack driver logging agent on compute engine instances. You can track your logs lively also you can create visualizations and useful analysis out of it. Stackdriver is the best industry standard for the people who is using GCP. remember the pricing. Please check the pricing details